# How to create a relation between two divs, one that holds products and other options

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I hope someone will be able to provide me with help for the following problem.
I am trying to hide or show items returned in the div based on the div's ID.
To be more specific, I am having a div that holds a number of different products. Also, there is another div that holds different number of options that are available and related to the certain product. My problem is that I don't know how to make a relation between those two so, that if specific product is selected only options that come with the selected product will be visible and others will be hidden.

Now, it is important to know that I have a function that returns the products and this function needs to be tweaked but, I just don't know how. I combed the internet to find a solution but, so far with no success. This is the function:

```
//load product by click
      var $productItemsWrapper = $sidebarContent.find('.fpd-products .fpd-items-wrapper');
      $productItemsWrapper.append('<picture><span class="fpd-loading"></span><img src="'+views[0].thumbnail+'" title="'+views[0].title+'" style="display:none;" /></picture>')
      .children('picture:last').click(function(evt) {

        var $this = $(this),
          index = $productItemsWrapper.children('picture').index($this);

        thisClass.selectProduct(index);

        evt.preventDefault();

      }).data('views', views)
      .children('img').load(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(500).prev('span').fadeOut(300, function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });
      });

      //show products in sidebar when there is more than 1
      if($productItemsWrapper.children('picture').length == 2) {
        $sidebarNavi.find('[data-target=".fpd-products"]').css('display', 'inline-block');
        _createScrollbar($productItemsWrapper);
      }

      $productItemsWrapper.perfectScrollbar('update');

    };
```

Here are divs that hold different options for products:

Option for product 1:

```
<div class="fpd-style" id="GCC67S"><img src="images/mizuno/gcc67s/web/web_base.png" data-parameters='{"x":220, "y": 229, "colors": "#dfd7c5,#000000,#ffffff,#990000"}' /></div>
```

Option for product 2:

```
<div class="fpd-style" id="test"><img src="images/mizuno/gcc67s/web/.png" data-parameters='{"x": 220, "y":229, "colors": "#dfd7c5,#000000,#ffffff,#990000"}' /></div>
```

Please note that I am at risk for being blocked from asking questions in the future apparently, due to lack of specifics when asking them so, I put effort into this question. Before marking me down please, please come forward and help me improve the question. I will give you any details you might need. I've tried to be as specific and detailed as possible but, maybe I still missed on providing some crucial information or my wording is still unclear.

I will be super thankful for any help offered.

Best regards and cheers.

Comment: Use jQuery classes to hide and show different options at different times.

Comment: James, thank you for the reply! I was trying that at first but since I have dynamic link I don't know how to call each specific class in that case.

Comment: I tried with this chunk of code but still doesn't do war is expected

Comment: $('.fpd-style').hide();
$('img').click(function(){
var target = "#" + $(this).data("target");
$(".fpd-style").not(target).hide();
$(target).show();
});

Answer (score 1):

You could use a data attribute to associate products to available options. Like `data-opts` here:

```
<div id="products">
    <div class="product" data-opts="0,1,3">Product 0</div>
    <div class="product" data-opts="2,3">Product 1</div>
    <div class="product" data-opts="0,2">Product 2</div>
</div>
<div id="options">
    <div class="option">Option 0</div>
    <div class="option">Option 1</div>
    <div class="option">Option 2</div>
    <div class="option">Option 3</div>    
</div>
```

And on click, you can show the options specified there, and hide the others.

```
$(".product").click(function productClick() {
    // make a number array from the data-opts, like [0,1,3]
    var opts = $(this).attr("data-opts").split(",").map(Number);
    $(".option").each(function optionEach(index) {
        // if index is in opts, show, otherwise hide
        $(this).toggle(opts.indexOf(index) > -1);
    });
});
```

This isn't based on your html, but I think you can apply this method to it.

Working [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zord/f5ebtgv9/). And another, id-based [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zord/f5ebtgv9/1/).

Comment: Zord, thanks a million for the suggestion. I am going to try to apply it now.

Comment: @DavorinSavovic Please consider accepting my answer if it helped to solve your problem.